# C#/Unity: Rotating triangles in 3D space to form a 2D polygon

Tags: math, vector, trigonometry

I have some triangles in 3D space, which originate from 0,0,0 and extend towards two points p1= -x0, 0, z0 and p2= +x0, 0, z0. This is in Unity, such that +z is the forward axis (i.e. they lie flat). Each triangle is its own mesh, pivot is at 0,0,0.

Now, I would like to rotate these (using `Quaternion.LookRotation`) such that their ends form a continuous polygon, in case of three triangles a triangle, in case of four triangles a square, etc.

My approach is to calculate the incircle radius of the resulting polygon based on the length of each triangle (which is 2*x0). If I now calculate n points on this circle (where n is the number of triangles I have), I get x/y coordinates which I can directly use to set the "up" axis of each triangle correctly, i.e. `Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, new Vector3(x,y,0))`. This orients the triangle correctly around the z axis, i.e. the center is still on 0,0,1.

However, and this has me stumped, I still need to change the forward axis of the triangles such that they tilt to form the final polygon. I tried using new `Vector3(x,y,z0)` which gives an almost correct result, but leads to an overlap at the edges. I suspect this is somehow due to the fact that rotation of the triangles effectively changes z0, but I am not sure how to proceed.

My question is, how to calculate the new forward axis such that the triangles align properly?

Comment: Its hard to say what is wrong without seeing some code or a screenshot, but here's how I would try to do it.  The face normal, triangle edge, and the cross of those form a reference frame (transform matrix).  So, what you can do is calculate the inverse transfrom from the current reference frame, to the reference frame you want to end up in.  From there, convert the transform matrix into euler angles.  Of course.. if the problem you are seeing is sub-pixel gaps, the only way to fix it is to merge the triangles into a single mesh when they are done rotating.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be more about maths than actually programming. I'ld suggest to rather put this on [Maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/). But it really isn't about Unity or c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is setting the forward axis to `(x,y,z0)`, which is wrong since the length of the vector `(x,y,z0)` does not equal the original length (which is just z0). The z value thus needs to be adjusted such that `new Vector(x,y,z1).magnitude == z0`. This can be done by calculating

`Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(z0, 2) - Mathf.Pow(x, 2) - Mathf.Pow(y, 2))`

Problem solved.